# How filter for a formated date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I get my data from a webservice, even when the date is `Date` the type is lost in translation. I solve the display part using a filter. But now the search need a tune up.

Right now I cant search `2016-xx` and of course there are more than 4 dates on year `2016`

[image]

**VIEW:** use the filter to convert the string to date and format

```
                 <!--  at-attribute show DateTime unformated value -->
<td at-implicit at-attribute="DateTime"
    at-title="Datetime" at-sortable at-initial-sorting="desc">
    {{item.DateTime | mydate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' }}                 
</td>
    <!--  mydate filter convert to Date and format -->
```

**How I change the filter here?**

**Controller:** This update the list to display on the table.

```
$scope.globalFilter = function () {
   $scope.filteredList = $filter("filter")($scope.cars, $scope.filter_global);
}
```

**Custom Filter**

```
app5.filter("mydate", function () {
    var re = /\/Date\(([0-9]*)\)\//;
    return function (x) {
        if (x !== null) {
            var m = x.match(re);
            if (m) return new Date(parseInt(m[1]));
            else return null;
        } else return null;
    };
});
```

**Sample array:**

```
   $scope.cars  = [
     {"Car_ID":2130,"X":121.01920100,"Y":14.51724100,"RoadName":null,"DateTime":"\/Date(1470231481000)\/"},
     {"Car_ID":1490,"X":121.10205000,"Y":14.25779300,"RoadName":"Eton Service Rd.","DateTime":"\/Date(1466735876000)\/"},
     {"Car_ID":2662,"X":121.03186700,"Y":14.49113200,"RoadName":null,"DateTime":"\/Date(1470226249000)\/"},
     {"Car_ID":2690,"X":121.03701700,"Y":14.61565000,"RoadName":"Dona Hemady","DateTime":"\/Date(1470122272000)\/"},
     {"Car_ID":2515,"X":121.02795800,"Y":14.56134900,"RoadName":"Makati Ave.","DateTime":"\/Date(1463770201000)\/"}
    ];
```

Comment: Can you provide a piece of your `array` structure? (in code).

Comment: @developer033 Datetime is a string like the one on the red box `/Date(1462016407000)/` dont know what you mean in code? the structure is the one show in the table `2016-04-30 07:40` is created by the filter I add

Comment: I mean if you could provide at least 2 items of your `array` structure to help us to debug your code.. The problem is with the customFilter, right?

Comment: the problem is with `$scope.filteredList = $filter("filter")($scope.cars, $scope.filter_global);`

Comment: What's `$scope.filter_global`?

Comment: @developer033 I can filter by a column or do global search. In that case global search check for date.

Comment: The problem is that we aren't seeing what's the content of `$scope.filter_global`..

Comment: In the picture you can see is `'2016'`

Comment: @developer033 I include a sample array, hope that help